# How to retrieve a particular row and column from a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two csv files which have user name and their different Id's. According to the users input I should be able to switch their Id's and retrieve it. Eg. the user inputs the student ID and wants the employee Id1 of a particular person name I should be able to retrieve it. I'm still very new to programming so I don't know much about programming. How do I do this? help me pleasee
A sample of my file

> Name, Student_id,EmployeeId1, Employee_Id2

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my1.csv")
colls = input("Enter the column")
roww = input("Enter the row")
df.loc ["roww","colls"]
```

The user will not know the rows and columns but I just wanted to try but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the row with label `"roww"` rather than what was input in the variable `roww`.

Try removing the quote marks, i.e.:

```
df.loc [roww, colls]
```

You might also have a problem that your row might be a number, and by default the value from `input` is a string. In this case try:

```
df.loc [int(roww),colls]
```

So for example, if your csv file was:

```
Name, Student_id,EmployeeId1, Employee_Id2
Bob, 1, 11, 12
Steve, 2, 21, 22
```

Then with input `Name` for column and `1` for row, you'd get `Steve` as the answer (since the rows start from 0.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this instead of asking for row and column input from the user?

Comment: You can use the set_index function to make one of the id values the row index, so instead of giving the row number, they instead give the Student_id for example; https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html

You can also do something like `df.loc[df['Name'] = 'Bob']` to get the rows relevant to the input.